# Laravel job executing real time without queue being started

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue, laravel-5.8

Running on Laravel 5.8
I am creating a large number of Jobs which I believe should be executed once the queue has been initiated.
My issue is that the jobs get executed then and there when I haven't even started the queue.

They are not even being inserted in to the `jobs` table created by the migration.

Below are the settings and the piece of code I believe is relevant. Please let me know if more info is needed.

On a fresh installation:

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
```

.env file

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

Created the queuedtask

```
class FulfillmentTask implements ShouldQueue{
//code here
}
```

Controller

```
use App\Jobs\FulfillmentTask;

//rest of the class here

public function somefunction(Request $request){
//some code here
//read csv file
foreach ($fileContents as $row){
            FulfillmentTask::dispatch($orderId, $client, $request->sendEmail)->onQueue('database');
        }
}
```

Issue is the FulfillmentTask is executed without the `queue:work` command being given in the terminal.

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: You want to try: onConnection('database') instead of onQueue('database')?

Comment: Worked as expected. Want to put it as an answer @KevinBui ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"database" is a queue connection. Pls dispatch your job to that connection.

```
FulfillmentTask::dispatch($orderId, $client, $request->sendEmail)->onConnection('database');
```

And that seems to be the default connection so you just dispatch the job.

```
FulfillmentTask::dispatch($orderId, $client, $request->sendEmail);
```